# How to create Breadcrumb list Schema - json

Tags: json, schema

I understand the general creation of the breadcrumbs.

Level 1 : Home / Level 2 : Blog / Level 3 : Title of the blog post.

I am unsure how level 3 works - is there a way to pull in the current page on the schema?

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
 "itemListElement":
 [
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
   "position": 1,
   "item":
   {
    "@id": "https://example.com/dresses",
    "name": "Dresses"
    }
  },
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
  "position": 2,
  "item":
   {
     "@id": "https://example.com/dresses/real",
     "name": "Real Dresses"
   },
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
  "position": 3,
  "item":
   {
     "@id": "https://example.com/dresses/real/",
     "name": "Current Page"
   }
  }
  }
 ]
}
</script>
```

So in my sample from schema.org I need the 3rd item to be the current page the user is on.....is this possible?

Example in google Search would display Sitename > Blog > News (if news was the name of the page).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Best answer I have found:

https://moz.com/blog/using-google-tag-manager-to-dynamically-generate-schema-org-json-ld-tags

Can use the js to build the tags in GTM.